# How to define the control points for a NURBS Torus Primitive

Tags: three.js, graphics, geometry, nurbs

I'm trying to build a donut (Torus) like shape using NURBS, but I can't seem to think of a way to define the control points.
There is a basic way to think of this problem, if we think of this as the definition of various circumferences along a big circumference, as seen in this [link](https://www.finalmesh.com/docs/help4/obj_nurbs_torus.htm).
Could anyone provide me with some insight or the control points to this problem?

I tried various ways of defining them but nothing seems to work and i'm getting desperate. Also I know this is not the best way to define this shape but I'm restricted to this type of abstraction.